# can dynamic memory allocation be considered as a procedure with O(1) space complexity..?

Tags: data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation, workspace, space-complexity, memory-efficient

If in a Program we need to temporarily manage some data and we dynamically create any data structure to store it and after the processing we delete that data structure which was dynamically created.Can this process be said to follow O(1) space complexity

Answer (score 0):

The big-O space complexity describes how the memory usage scales with the number or size of specific inputs.

For example, if you had an algorithm to process a matrix with R rows and C columns, and the amount of memory your processing required was constant even as R and C increased, then your algorithm would have O(1) space complexity.

When the memory used is dynamically allocated or not is orthogonal, though the *lifetime* of allocation is relevant.  Consider:

- if you visit each cell in a matrix and allocate a *fixed* (i.e. not growing with R and C) amount of memory, process the cell, then deallocate the memory *before* proceeding to the next cell, then your peak memory usage would be independent of R and C, so O(1) space complexity, but
- if you allocated a fixed amount of memory as you visited each cell, and only deallocated it all *after* processing the last cell, then your memory usage would have been scaling  with the number of cells - O(R*C) space complexity
- if you visit each cell and allocate an amount of memory that tends to grow with the values of R and/or C, then your space complexity *won't* be O(1)